# spring Access static resources 404

Tags: java, spring

I used WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/profile/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:"+ MatConfig.getUploadPath());
}
```

MatConfig.getUploadPath path is \home\tablo\uploadpath\upload

Mapping, but every visit is 404, I don’t know why, and I can’t find any problem with my configuration. After the file is uploaded, it will indeed exist in the
"/home/tablo/uploadpath/upload"  directory, but the access is similar to http Addresses like
"localhost:8865/profile/6b0c5968-1d82-468f-b2bf-fbc3a2044349.jpg"
are always 404, but strangely, when I set the address to the address under windows, it can be accessed

Answer (score 0):

That is, the same configuration works on Windows, but gives a 404 error on Linux, right? Maybe problem is the directory permissions?

Comment: I found the problem, because I added an extra "/"